# Wait for a VkFence in a thread before it has been submitted by another thread

Tags: vulkan

I'm implementing asynchronous VkCommandBuffer recording to improve geometry and texture loading in my rendering engine.

I'm facing validation issue about VkFence being in use in two different threads:

> UNASSIGNED-Threading-MultipleThreads(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 337425955 - Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-MultipleThreads ] Object 0: handle = 0x90a67000000088d3, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_FENCE; | MessageID = 0x141cb623 | THREADING ERROR : vkQueueSubmit(): object of type VkFence is simultaneously used in thread 0x3344 and thread 0x2d3c

I've written a minimal example to reproduce my issue here: https://gist.github.com/siliace/fc2633ee2406d3cbc53a60857bb14776

When on line 18, `gSubmitBeforeWaitFence` is `false`, the worker thread will not wait until the main thread submitted the fence to wait for it, causing my validations errors.
When `gSubmitBeforeWaitFence` is `true`, everything is fine.

Is it a bug of the validation layer and I should not have to wait for a VkFence to be submitted before waiting for it? Or is it a mistake from me? I would expect vkWaitForFences to be read-only operation so I don't see the point of forbiding this use.

And if my usage is wrong, is it written somewhere in the spec? I could not find it neighter in the documentation of vkQueueSubmut nor vkWaitForFences.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's hard to trace through your code, since it's all locked behind Vulkan wrappers rather than explicitly using the API. I would do some logging of commands; it's possible that you're using the same fence twice in vkQueueSubmit commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not allowed to use a fence while it is being `vkQueueSubmit`ed:

> ## Host Synchronization
>
> - Host access to `queue` **must** be externally synchronized
> - Host access to `fence` **must** be externally synchronized

Comment: That was indeed written... Thanks for your help !